# How to define a remote uploads directory?

Tags: uploads, wp-config, remote

Using the constant overrides in wp-config I'm able to define a remote FTP server that plugins will be added to when installed using the WP interface.

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'ftpext');
define('FTP_BASE', '/');
define('FTP_CONTENT_DIR', '/public_html/example.com/wp-content/');
define('FTP_PLUGIN_DIR', '/public_html/example.com/wp-content/plugins/');
define('FTP_USER', 'username');
define('FTP_PASS', 'password');
define('FTP_HOST', '123.123.123.123');
```

What's weird to me is that there isn't a constant setup for themes or uploads. Themes I don't care about (but its still weird) ... I want uploads to be put on the remote server though. Ideally there would be an `FTP_UPLOADS_DIR` that could be overwritten the same way.

Any ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: try setting `WP_CONTENT_DIR` to the wp-content directory the rest should be done for you by WordPress.

Comment: Agreed you can use the WP_CONTENT_DIR as per the [codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_wp-content)

Comment: Also note that it does not matter if you use a cdn to load the objects to but might involve extra coding for uploads

Comment: Setting `WP_CONTENT_DIR` doesn't change anything. You're required to set `WP_PLUGIN_DIR` even if you set wp-content. Either way, it doesn't affect uploads.

I realized, though, that plugins and WP upgrades are done via FTP. File uploads, however, use PHP -- not FTP. So a wp-config change may not be the route to take.

Comment: See related question and answer: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52042/upload-file-to-remote-storage

Answer (score 1):

IMHO a better approach would be adding the remote server's directory as a locally mounted directory and use this as wp-content directory. Doing this on the block/filesystem level means that WordPress won't notice a thing, since it appears to WordPress as normal local directory. You may want to have a look at sshfs in order to mount the directory. Using this has the added benefits of:

- not having to put your ftp password in file
- no (slow/unreliable) php code having to act as ftp client
- no need for ftp an insecure protocol by itself
- no need for a ftp-server on the remote server
- no need to change WordPress config